# Lomb Scargle with time series Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, astropy

I have a problem with Lomb Scargle in time series in Pandas. I get data with datetime index and I would like to do a Lomb Scargle transformation on my data. My data look like this:

```
1993-01-01           NaN
1993-02-01           NaN
1993-03-01           NaN
1993-04-01           NaN
1993-05-01           NaN
1993-06-01           NaN
1993-07-01           NaN
1993-08-01    270.050000
1993-09-01    281.746667
1993-10-01    283.950000
1993-11-01    276.165385
1993-12-01    263.510345
1994-01-01    255.803226
1994-02-01    254.784091
1994-03-01    256.736207
1994-04-01    254.211667
1994-05-01    250.385000
1994-06-01    250.281667
1994-07-01    251.145161
1994-08-01    262.219355
1994-09-01    276.787037
1994-10-01    281.126667
1994-11-01    276.345000
1994-12-01    267.536207
1995-01-01    265.230000
1995-02-01    263.682692
1995-03-01    262.801724
1995-04-01    258.081034
1995-05-01    251.637500
1995-06-01    255.075000
.
.
.
2014-07-01    260.993548
2014-08-01    274.343548
2014-09-01    283.983333
2014-10-01    290.995161
2014-11-01    286.183333
```

I tried a code like this:

```
import numpy as np
from astroML.time_series import lomb_scargle, search_frequencies

def lomb(data):
    t = np.arange(0, len(data), 1)
    dy = 0.5 + 0.5 * np.random.random(len(data))
    omega = (2*np.pi)/t
    PS = lomb_scargle(t, data.values, dy, omega, generalized=True)
    return pd.Series(PS, index = omega)
```

But I would like to introduce my time index to obtain a Lomb Scargle periodogram with month in x axis. I am not sure that my omega et t variables is correct as inputs.